# Securing the SSL clientkey pair in android

Tags: android, ssl, authentication

I am using certificate for SSL client authentication in android. Keystore containing certificate is being stored inside /res directory.

What bothers me is that keystore in res folder is visible inside apk when opened with zip utility.Now if someone were to decompile my code and get the keystore key, he/she can impersonate my app.

Any suggestions to protect that.

Comment: Hi Simon,I didn't find any acceptable answer out there.